# How to store the results of a command to a variable?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm trying to build a context menu that will show a tree structure of all my packages and their resources. Something like this terrible MS Paint rendering I drew:

[image]

I have [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) installed. It offers **commands** that show in a window. But I would like to use them to populate these sub-context menues:

- `get_packages_list` that I think will populate the first sub-menu (packages)
- `list_package_files` that should populate each subsequent sub-menu

However, I'm not sure how to get the output of these into a context menu. I've been looking at python (writing a sublime plugin for this).

**How do I get the output of these commands into a variable?**

---

**My Code**

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


    class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit):
            self.view.insert(edit, 0, package_resource_viewer)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
>>> view.window().run_command("example")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 818, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File "C:\Users\heete\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\hello_world.py", line 7, in run
    self.view.insert(edit, 0, package_resource_viewer)
```

> `NameError: global name 'package_resource_viewer' is not defined`

Obviously I haven't gotten far, but I can't even get the output of this to show in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can import and access those commands. I made a minimal example, which prints the packages to the current view.
However output the to a context/sidebar menu seems to be harder, because they are usually static and you cannot just create one dynamically. (You may try to create a static menu file via a command.)

```py
import sublime_plugin

from PackageResourceViewer.package_resources import (
    get_packages_list, list_package_files
)


class ExampleListPackagesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        packages = get_packages_list()

        insert_sb = []
        insert_sb.append("Installed Packages:")
        insert_sb.extend(packages)

        for package in packages:
            insert_sb.append("")
            insert_sb.append(package)

            package_files = list_package_files(package)

            insert_sb.extend("\t" + pf for pf in package_files)

        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "\n".join(insert_sb))
```